# my jquery button doesn't work when I click the first time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use javascript and jquery to do some plotting, here is the code that I define the button, but the first time I click it doesn't work, the second time it works well, I don't understand why.

```
$('<p><input type="button" value="Plot Data" /></p>').click(getData).appendTo('#plot');
```

Could someone help to explain it?
Thanks!

Mengfei

Comment: You're going to have to reveal what _getData()_ does. It *might* help to append the element to the DOM first, and then to attach the event handler, but maybe not.

Comment: Hi, getData() downloads data from another server and plot it in flot, I don't quite understand you meaning by "appedn to the element to the DOM",could you explain little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var 
  // function for event click
  getData = function(ev) {
      alert('ok');
  },
  // your button
  button = $('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />').click(getData),
  // append to p container
  pcontainer = $('<p></p>').append(button).appendTo('#plot');
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/qXXAn/)

**EDIT for comments**

```
var 
  // counter clicks
  clickCounter = 0,
  // function for event click
  getData = function(ev) {

      $('#controlClick').append('click in getData '+(++clickCounter)+'<br />'); // firsts lines

      // your code;
      // don't put return false or ev.stopPropagation()
  },
  controlEvent = function(ev) {
      $('#controlClick').append('click in control<br />');
  },
  // your button
  button = $('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />')
    .bind('click', getData)
    .bind('click', controlEvent),
  // append to p container
  pcontainer = $('<p></p>').append(button).appendTo('#plot');​
```

[example update](http://jsfiddle.net/qXXAn/1/)

Comment: Hi Andres, thank you for the example, I changed with your code, but it still needs twice click, maybe there's something wrong with my getData function...really confused now.

Comment: try this simple event handling

Answer (score 0):

Because the click action is on 'p'. Jquery will return the object of the outer html, in your case 'p'. Try this instead:

```
$('#plot').append($('<p></p>').append($('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />').wrap('').click(getData)));
```

Comment: `$('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />').click(getData).wrap('<p />').parent().appendTo('#plot');` :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "p" tags from your code?